# don't know how to print word from dictionary after user input

Tags: python

so i'm fairly new to using python and I wanted to make a list of popular pets and have the person type in a number (that's assigned to an animal from a list of 10 in a dictionary) and print the correct animal from the number they typed in.

so far this is my code:

```py
import random
import time

var = {"Ferret": 4, "Iguana": 8, "Snake": 2, "Bird": 5, "Guinea Pig": 9, "Mice": 10, "Fish": 7, "Hamster": 1, "Cat": 6,
       "Dog": 3}
pets = ['Ferret, Iguana, Snake, Bird, Guinea Pig, Mice, Fish, Hamster, Cat, Dog']

for choice in random.choices(pets):
    time.sleep(1)
    print(choice)

var: int = int(input('Enter a number between 1 & 10: '))
```

the thing i'm having trouble with is having the input print the animal after the user typed in that animals number.

Comment: What sort of trouble? What did you try, and how did it fail? Do you understand how to fetch the value corresponding to a key in a dictionary?

Comment: It would be easier to have integer value on key of the doctor instead of value. If you can't change, you only need to make a loop on dictionary values and compare to input.

Comment: that's it I don't know how to fetch the value. What I was trying is this: if var: var = 4 print('Ferret'). or whatever the value is

Comment: The formatting errors make this hard to read, but it looks like you are replacing `var` the dictionary with an `int` from the user's input. You need to use two different variables for this, with distinct names. (`var` is arguably not a good name for either of them. Perhaps `animal` for the dictionary and `choice` for the user's selection?)

Comment: ok I renamed the dictionary and replaced 'int' with choice. but I still don't know how to fetch the word in the dictionary with the assigned value and print that word from the typed in value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, two problems you have here.

First of all, a dictionary is like a door. You need a key to open a door. What is on the other side of the door is your value.

In your case, you want to access an animal, based on a number. The number will be a key and the animal will be your value.

So first step would be to reverse your dictionary key and values.

The second would be to change how you take an input and store it in a variable. Not like

```
var: int = int(input('Enter a number between 1 & 10: '))
```

Third thing, it's not a problem but an additional feature. You want to print the value of a key. You can use `dict.get(key)`

**code**

```
import random
import time

var = {4:"Ferret", 8:"Iguana", 2:"Snake", 5:"Bird", 9:"Guinea Pig", 10:"Mice", 7:"Fish", 1:"Hamster", 6:"Cat",
       "Dog": 3}
pets = ['Ferret, Iguana, Snake, Bird, Guinea Pig, Mice, Fish, Hamster, Cat, Dog']

for choice in random.choices(pets):
    time.sleep(1)
    print(choice)

num = int(input('Enter a number between 1 & 10: '))
print(var.get(num))
```

Comment: You solved my issue thank you soooo much! i'm like brand new to python so this is a huge help!

Comment: If this helped, you can accept the answer. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers